# facerecognizer.java class in Opencv4Android 2.4.9

Tags: android, opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to use facerecognizer.java class in Opencv4Android 2.4.9

I have created Recognizer class that inherits from FaceRecognizer class in its constructor, some address should be sent to the super class's constructor. I am not able to send that address here is the code of constructor:

```
public Recognizer(long addr) {
    super(addr); <- **problem is here what should i send**????
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

what should be sent as address ?? I tried different long values but it gives Segfault error. I found an answer having suggestions of native objects and jni but I don't know how to use them here is the link:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/4490/facerecognizerjava-in-opencv4android-243/

Please help me what I need to do? A lot of thanks!!!!!

Comment: "it gives Segfault error" Is there such a thing like segmentation fault in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an android.media.FaceDetector class in the Android SDK. Maybe it will help you.